# Parallel execution of async Task<T> methods in loop

Tags: c#, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

I have a program with a `async Task<Result>` method, than I need to run in parallel from a loop.
Here are two ways I tried, the first one (`ResolveWidgetsTaskFactoryAsync`) works as expected, but the other (`ResolveWidgetsNotParallelAsync`) runs synchronously, even if each method returns as Task.
While keeping async `Task<string>` return type of `ComputeAsync`, how can I write better my parallel version ?

```
void Main()
{
    var results = ResolveWidgetsTaskFactoryAsync().Result;
    results.Dump();

    results = ResolveWidgetsNotParallelAsync().Result;
    results.Dump();
}

/// <summary>
/// Runs synchronously instead of in parallel
/// /summary>
private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> ResolveWidgetsNotParallelAsync()
{
    var values = new[] { "a", "b", "c" };
    var widgets = new List<Task<string>>();

    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Iteration value : " + value);

        var widgetTask = ComputeAsync(value);
        widgets.Add(widgetTask);
    }

    return await Task.WhenAll(widgets);
}

/// <summary>
/// Runs as expected, but I'm not sure it's well written
/// /summary>
private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> ResolveWidgetsTaskFactoryAsync()
{
    var values = new[] { "a", "b", "c" };
    var widgets = new List<Task<string>>();

    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Iteration value : " + value);

        widgets.Add(Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => ComputeAsync(value).Result));
    }

    return await Task.WhenAll(widgets);
}

public async Task<string> ComputeAsync(string value)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Processing value : " + value);

        Random rnd = new Random();
        var wait = rnd.Next(1000, 5000);
        Console.WriteLine("Wait : " + wait);
        Thread.Sleep(wait);

        return await Task.FromResult(value + " done");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: because there is nothing async in `ComputeAsync`

Comment: replace `Thread.Sleep(wait);` with `await Task.Delay(wait);` , then try again.

Comment: Do not mix `Task<T>` with `Thread.Sleep(wait);` There is nothing async in this line as well `widgets.Add(Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => ComputeAsync(value).Result));` `Result` is blocking call

Comment: I didn't know Task.Delay, thanks !
But my real world version also exhibits the same behavior than my example even if the method is a "real" awaitable process, I will dig why.

Comment: Can you use [async main](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main)?

Comment: `Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => ComputeAsync(value).Result)` this is bad on many level. Why are you calling `Factory.StartNew` for an already Task based method? And why are you using a blocking call `.Result`? You should do `widgets.Add(ComputeAsync(value));` and get rid of `Thread.Sleep` in favor of `Task.Delay`

Comment: @PeterBons I'm perfectly agree that's bad :).
But when I posted the question it was the way that worked, hence why I asked for explanation and a better approach. I didn't know await Task.Delay which made my simple example above to work as expected.
And concerning my real world method, I found where the problem was, one of the "long" methods called by it was not awaited properly, so it runned synchronously !
Thanks everybody, and especially Fildor who was the first to point Task.Delay(wait);

Comment: Note that *parallel* and *async* are two completely separate concepts. Neither implies the other.

Comment: @Alejandro Yeah, I know, hence my question to know how to have both in a single writing. Thank you :).

Answer (score 2):

To write the parallel version in a better way, you should start by realizing that your code is synchronous in nature. There is nothing asynchronous in it. Wrapping synchronous code in an asynchronous API will just have complexity and confusion as a result. So my advice is to strip all `Task`, `async` and `await` keywords from your code, and use the [`Parallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel) class or the [PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq) library in order to parallelize it. Below is a PLINQ example:

```
public string Compute(string value)
{
    //...
}

private string[] ResolveWidgetsParallel()
{
    var values = new[] { "a", "b", "c" };
    return values
        .AsParallel()
        .AsOrdered()
        .Select(value => Compute(value))
        .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I know also this approach but I had to keep "async Task<>" so I was wanting to know the best way to write relying on async C# feature.

Comment: @AFract it would be interesting if you could provide more info about why you need to maintain async signatures to methods that have synchronous implementations. This is not unprecedented, for example the abstract class `TextReader` does it with its [`ReadLineAsync`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textreader.readlineasync) method, but this is intended to be overridden by the derived implementations of the class. In general it's considered bad practice to not honor the asynchronous contract, and forcing the caller to do all the work instead of returning an incomplete task.